# Abort and resume terraform apply

Tags: terraform

Some resources create a very long timespan, up to hours, to be created.
I would like to use terraform in a ci deployment pipeline, but I want to prevent running the job for like 8 hours just waiting for resource creation.

Is it possible to pause/abort terraform execution and resync the state at a later time, for example 24 hours after each run.

The problem in my case is creating a azure cdn endpoint with cdn managed tls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to pause a Terraform Apply. You can only discard a run, but it will send a SIGINT to providers and they will handle the cancelation, mostly they will stop the process of creating the resources.
As a workaround for this, you can split your project into multiple terraform workspaces. With that approach, you will not block other resources, by long-running Terraform Apply on the Azure CDN service.

Comment: good idea to split the project into multiple terraform ... we could even use other tools to create those resources that take a long time in a fire and forget that way we do not consume the time of a pipeline

Comment: @HelderSepulveda HashiCorp recommends to split project into multiple independent workspaces [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cloud-docs/recommended-practices/part1)

Comment: when you are a hammer everything is a nail... I agree with split the project, I do that all the time there are great reasons to do that... but if a job runs for 8 hours just waiting for resource creation, I would reconsider using terraform for it, use something else, one less job running in your pipeline